# Django - выборка из раздела и подразделов

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, ниже приведен код из **views.py** который делает выборку всех статей по разделу.
Но если статьи привязаны к дочернему разделу - то ничего не выбирается. Как мне выбрать все статьи по корневому разделу, чтобы выбрать все из всех дочерних подразделов???

```
def article_section(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    object_list = Article.objects.all()

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(category=category)

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    sections = Category.objects.all()

    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(
        request,
        'articles/list.html',
        {
            'page': page,
            'category': category,
            'sections': sections,
            'articles': articles,
        }
    )
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, надо получить все категории дочерние по отношению к выбранной. Если используется [mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt), то вопрос решается просто: `categories = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)`. Если не используется, то поможет рекурсивная функция. После получения списка категорий:

```
object_list = object_list.filter(category__in=categories)
```

Comment: Не сразу понял, немного погуглив, нашел несколько похожих примеров.
Сделал так:

`object_list = object_list.filter(category__in=category.get_descendants(include_self=True))`

Работает! Огромное спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Для спасибо есть кнопка "Принять".